# Is it possible to send transactions to multiple recipients?

Tags: transactions, ether, accounts, bitcoin

In other blockchain based platforms, it's possible to send transactions to multiple recipients. For instance, if I want to send 13 ETH to Alice and 7 ETH to Bob, Bitcoin has `sendmany`. Is it possible to accomplish this in one Ethereum transaction?

Or would I have to create a contract which forwards the ether?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The recipient of an Ethereum transaction can only ever be a single entity, as specified by the Yellow Paper (http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) page 4, section 4.2, `to` field.

However as you mentioned, a contract can itself create multiple transactions as a result of a single invocation.

Comment: Also, a contract may send to multiple addresses in a single transaction.

Answer (score -1):

@péter-szilágyi I think we can also achieve this by taking the multiple addresses in as argument and using the send transaction we could send it in one go